# Unable to start Redis server due to config file error

Tags: redis

I've just installed Redis by following the instructions here: http://redis.io/download

When I run redis-server redis.conf I get the following error:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 135
>>> 'slave-serve-stale-data yes'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[I had this problem, too](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/259), and had to manually copy files into place after the build.

```
cd ~/redis-2.4.15
mkdir redis-1.2.4-backup

sudo mv /usr/bin/redis-* ~/redis-2.4.15/redis-1.2.4-backup/ ;

sudo mv src/redis-benchmark /usr/bin/ ;
sudo mv src/redis-check-aof /usr/bin/ ;
sudo mv src/redis-check-dump /usr/bin/ ;
sudo mv src/redis-cli /usr/bin/ ;
sudo mv src/redis-server /usr/bin/ ;

sudo chown root /usr/bin/redis-* ;
```

I put the `;` at the ends of the lines because sometimes I want to join things into a single line of shell commands.

Make sure the rest of your stuff is setup, like `init.d`, `conf` and `log` files.

Answer (score 2):

where trying to install make sure you have necessary read/write permissions. on ubuntu make sure you run like

```
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I had,

Firstly I tried to compile and install. But wont work. Secondly, I added epel repo and use yum install redis.

The problem is the remaining files/folders have conflict.

So, clean all of your previous installation/s and start a clean one.