# Redis read config file error:

Tags: database, configuration, nosql, redis, config

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 135
>>> 'slave-serve-stale-data yes'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

[The same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367713/unable-to-start-redis-server-due-to-config-file-error)

but i don't installed old version(redis version is 2.4.10), connot run src/redis-server (where had `src` dir?), my system is archlinux, install by pacman.

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? Please, run `redis-server --version` to confirm.

Comment: Redis server version 2.4.10 (00000000:0)

Comment: I got the same err with "slave-priority" instead of "slave-serve-stale-data". Just commented that line and redis works fine. And yes, that's a dirty fix.

Comment: @酿泉为酒 You are welcome :) A few weeks ago I've updated to latest Redis and everything went fine. Maybe you wanna give shot.